# How to open file for writing in shared mode in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to open file in shared mode for editing (other processes must have access to that file for writing as well) under Windows OS. Is it possible in Perl?
For example, in WinApi there is a possibility to specify flag FILE_SHARE_WRITE in CreateFile() function.
Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to use [`createFile`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32API::File#createFile) from [Win32API::File](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32API::File).

Answer (score -1):

Multiple processes writing to the same file is a bad situation.  An example would be a database scenario where a table must be locked by a processes in order to changes to be written to the table reliably.  You could write something that does nothing else but listen to the other processes to write to the file.

perlmonks suggest using `flock`

[Here's the link.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=672403)  Hope this helps!